# AWS KMS Encryption enable for SQL Server Columns?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-rds, aws

Is it possible MSSQL on EC2 with a key in AWS KMS to encrypt columns

Answer (score 0):

As per sql server blog [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/41003f1f-3a7d-4c24-afb8-0fa60efffac1/can-i-use-aws-kms-as-column-master-key-store-for-sql-server-always-encrypted?forum=sqlsecurity) On SQL Server side, [it is supported to use a custom key store provider for Always Encrypted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-column-master-key-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), but the implementation/support of the custom key store provider comes from the service provider itself, which in this case is the AWS KMS.

For further your ref [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/how-to-encrypt-database-columns-with-no-impact-on-your-application-using-aws-dms-and-baffle/)

Comment: We have planned to use AWS KMS custom keys with application code

Answer (score 0):

We can't download the KMS key for custom master key creation , We need to use the kms encryption key with application code